# Cant start .Net6 Program on Raspberry Pi

Tags: .net, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on an Raspi 4b with an quite old OS (Raspbian 10). I really don't want to upgrade this, because it's an special Image from the manufacturer of the Hardware I'm using (with pre-installed drivers etc.). And the Raspi is permanently offline...

In the last years I am mostly program in C# .Net ....mostly for Windows but a few times also for Linux Systems (which worked very well!). So decide to program my stuff in .Net 6.

But I cant start my tool with my normal user (also not with sudo) but with root.

So I first install .Net on my Pi (https://www.petecodes.co.uk/install-and ... pberry-pi/) and try :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dotnet --version
6.0.407
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dotnet --version
6.0.407
```

This works very well but if I try to start my program:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/mypath/tool $ ./TOOL
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/pi/mypath/tool/TOOL
Architecture: arm
App host version: 6.0.15
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?mi ... ion=6.0.15
```

Its the same Issue with sudo....

BUT if I try to run the Tool on root everything works great:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/mypath/tool# ./TOOL
TOOL was started...
```

Why can I start my program with root-user but not with other users and also not with sudo?
Thanks for your help...